# SQL Query with Typo not working in MySQL (Order by on calculated field)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, calculated-columns

I have this query in which one of the column is a calculated one. Every thing is working except it is not ordering the results when I use that calculated column in query. The query is a very large one so I have simplified it below for understanding. Here the calculated column is "remaining"

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.duration - datediff(now(), t1.posting_time) as "remaining"
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE td.id = t1.timefield
 ORDER BY id, name, remaining DESC
```

Even if I remove this "remaining" from order by clause or use it with asc or desc, nothing happens and order stays the same.

Comment: please give an example of unsorted data, how it's sorted now and what you except.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time when 'remaining' alters the sort order is when the id and the name in two rows are the same.  Otherwise, it has no effect on the ordering.

You need to fix the typo of '`td.id`' to '`t2.id`'.

You should learn the JOIN notation too:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.duration - datediff(now(), t1.posting_time) as "remaining"
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.timefield
 ORDER BY id, name, remaining DESC
```

Comment: Yes they are same but still using "remaining" has no effect on order of results.
Is there any difference between join I used and the one you showed? I mean will it solve my problem or is there any performance upgrade?

Comment: Ok I just found out something. When I use more than 3 columns in order by then it just ignores column after the 3rd one. So if there is 4th column then it is ignored. Is there a limit on columns I can use in order by clause?

Comment: Ok I got it now. You are right. I am looking the wrong way. "Remaining" has not effect on order because id and name are not same. Dang! now how am I going to order it using "remaining" hmmm.....

Comment: @Ali: if you want to order things by the time remaining, list it first in the ORDER BY clause.  If t1.id is the PK of the data, ordering by t1.id first completely orders the data on its own, unless there are multiple rows in t2 for each row in t1.

Answer (score 1):

use a trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.id, 
    t1.name, 
    t2.duration - datediff(now() , t1.posting_time) as "remaining"
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
  WHERE t2.id = t1.timefield
  ) AS i
ORDER BY id, name, remaining DESC
```

Comment: This is a neat trick but I am not sure if it will be feasible in my case as I am using 6 tables to join and I have read that derived tables have performance overhead when used in joins!?

Comment: Strangely when I ran your query in simplified form, the order clause worked with column "remaining". But when I used it in full query with 6 tables then I am facing same problem. It is just ignoring "remaining" column.

Comment: I first thought "not worked" means an SQL error but it looks it's more a question of "the sort order is not the same as you excepted"

Comment: Ok I just found out something. When I use more than 3 columns in order by then it just ignores column after the 3rd one. So if there is 4th column then it is ignored. Is there a limit on columns I can use in order by clause?

Comment: it has nothing to to do with the amount of columns but the sequence of the columns. it's first ordered by first column than second etc. and at some point adding more columns becomes ambiguous and has no further effect. (that's what Jonathan also explained in his answer)